# Should the declaration order affect TypeScript type deduction?

Tags: typescript, overloading

It seems that TypeScript's translator somehow relies on the order of declaration, at least in case of overloaded functions.

Lets say we have classes for 2- and 3-dimensional vectors:

```js
class Vector2 {
  public get x() : number
  public get y() : number
}
class Vector3 {
  public get x() : number
  public get y() : number
  public get z() : number
}
```

And we have an overloaded function which accepts either `Vector2` or `Vector3`:

```js
function add(a : Vector2, b : number) : Vector2;
function add(a : Vector3, b : number) : Vector3;
```

Depending on which signature of `add()` goes first - with `Vector2` or `Vector3` result - the compiler may deduce different type of the result, even if we pass as a parameter exactly `Vector3`.
For instance, in case of the same order as mentioned above, the following code:

```js
const r = add(new Vector3, 5)
```

Will return `Vector2` instead of `Vector3`.
Because of this, if we put constraints on the possible type of `r` as `Vector3`:

```js
const r : Vector3 = add(new Vector3, 5)
```

the code will not compile.

Is this should to be so? Because for me it looks like an error in the translator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour of Typescript: when you call an overloaded function, the compiler chooses the *first* overload signature which is compatible at the call-site, not the *most-specific* signature. From [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#function-overloads):

> TypeScript chooses the *first matching overload* when resolving function calls. When an earlier overload is “more general” than a later one, the later one is effectively hidden and cannot be called.

Since your `Vector3` is a [structural subtype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) of your `Vector2`, the `Vector3` overload signature is more specific so you should write that one before the `Vector2` overload signature.